# VS Code extension - programmatically find keybindings

Tags: visual-studio-code, key-bindings, vscode-extensions

When programming a *vscode* extension...
Is there a programmatic way to find the keybinding for a provided command?

I would like to be able to see if a user has updated the key mapping from default for a command so that the UI can display the up-to-date binding. (and if not, look up the default binding)

Here are the APIs I've looked into so far:

- `vscode.workspace.getConfiguration()` - I cannot determine how to access the `keybindings.json` file / perform a lookup.
- `vscode.extensions.getExtension(name/id)` allows access to the `package.json`, but not the command or keybinding override.
- `vscode.getCommands` does not provide access to the keybinding values either...

Answer (score 3):

You can get keybinding values from the keybindings.json file using NodeJS.

keybindings.json path on diferrent systems:

```
Windows: %APPDATA%\Code\User\keybindings.json
Mac: $HOME/Library/Application Support/Code/User/keybindings.json
Linux: $HOME/.config/Code/User/keybindings.json
```

To build the path you'll need to get Environment variables using process.env.{variableName}.

For example for MacOS it'll be:

```js
var process = require('process');
//...
var keybindingsPath = process.env.HOME + "/Library/Application Support/Code/User/keybindings.json";

vscode.workspace.openTextDocument(keybindingsPath).then((document) => {
    let text = document.getText();
    //then use this JSON file for your needs
    //...
});
```

Comment: NB: VSC profile folder location can be specified by parameters, i.e. outside the system user profile folder, see http://stackoverflow.com/q/49667641/

Comment: For portable version it's `process.env.VSCODE_PORTABLE + "/user-data/User/keybindings.json"`

Comment: Now, how do we parse that JSON file? We can't use `JSON.parse()` because it's non-standard - json with comments

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by @nikita-kunevich answer Here is a code I use in autoit extension.

First it gets default keybindings from `package.json`, then it parses `keybindings.json` via [JSON5](https://github.com/json5/json5) library (can't use `JSON.parse()` because file may contain comments) and replaces default keys with new keys.

```
//get keybindings
const keybindings = new Promise(resolve => {
  //default keybindings
  const data = require("../package.json").contributes.keybindings.reduce((a,b)=>(a[b.command]=b.key,a),{});
  const parse = list => {
    for(let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
      if (list[i].command in data)
        data[list[i].command] = list[i].key;
    }
    for(let i in data) {
      //capitalize first letter
      data[i] = data[i].replace(/\w+/g, w => (w.substring(0,1).toUpperCase()) + w.substring(1));
      //add spaces around "+"
      // data[i] = data[i].replace(/\+/g, " $& ");
    }

    Object.assign(keybindings, data);
    resolve(data);
  };
  const path = {
    windows: process.env.APPDATA + "/Code",
    macos: process.env.HOME + "/Library/Application Support/Code",
    linux: process.env.HOME + "/config/Code"
  }[{
    aix: "linux",
    darwin: "macos",
    freebsd: "linux",
    linux: "linux",
    openbsd: "linux",
    sunos: "linux",
    win32: "windows"
  }[process.platform]||"windows"];
  const file = ((process.env.VSCODE_PORTABLE ? process.env.VSCODE_PORTABLE + "/user-data/User/" : path) + "/User/keybindings.json")
    .replace(/\//g, process.platform == "win32" ? "\\" : "/");

  //read file
  workspace.openTextDocument(file).then(doc => {
    //we can't use JSON.parse() because file may contain comments
    const JSON5 = require("json5").default;
    parse(JSON5.parse(doc.getText()));
  }).catch(er => {
    parse([]);
  });
});
```

To install JSON5 package use:

```
npm install json5
```

Usage:

```
keybindings.then(list => {
  console.log(list);
});
```