# Launch VSC with clean or custom profile

Tags: visual-studio-code

Normally VSC stores settings and user data in `%appdata%\Code` (and extensions in `%userprofile%\.vscode`.

Is there a way to tell new instance to load some other profile or start with a "blank canvas" (like you can do with Firefox using `-no-remote -profile "path\to\profile"` command line arguments)?

It would be great for testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible and documented in [Advanced CLI options](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/command-line#_advanced-cli-options), arguments:

> `--user-data-dir <dir>` Specifies the directory that user data is kept in, useful when running as root.
>
> `--extensions-dir <dir>` Sets the root path for extensions.

So creating shortcut with both arguments provides possibility to have a "vanilla" VSC instance launcher:

```
code --extensions-dir "C:\tmp-exts" --user-data-dir "C:\tmp-profile"
```

Important: make sure you are invoking correct `code` executable: it should be `\VSCode\bin\code.cmd`, **not** the `\VSCode\Code.exe` ([bug?](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/57185)).

VSCode now supports [portable mode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/portable), i.e. folder called `data` located in applications directory takes precedence over appdata (and for now even over command line switches, [bug?](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/63657)).

Answer (score 0):

And see https://stackoverflow.com/a/73589372/836330 for more on creating and using a temporary profile that includes no extensions.

---

You could create your own settings profile and then reuse that for testing or to set up a new machine.  Load with a custom profile, see [Settings Profile, v1.67 Release Notes](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_67.md#settings-profile).

> #### Import/Export Settings Profile
>
> In this milestone we introduced Settings Profile that is a collection
> of your settings, extensions and UI customizations. If you customized
> VS Code, you can now export your customizations to a Settings Profile
> file (`mysetup.code-profile`) and save it to your computer and share
> it with others. Following gif shows exporting a Settings Profile from
> VS Code:

[image: Creating a settings Profile]

> You can also import a Settings Profile file to restore your
> customizations. Following gif shows importing a Settings Profile into
> VS Code:

[image: Import a Settings profile]

> You can host your Settings Profile file in the Internet, for example
> save it as a public GitHub gist, and share the URL with others. One
> can import the Settings Profile file by providing the URL.
>
> Note: At present only following UI customizations are included in the
> Settings Profile. More will be added in the future.
>
> Status bar items visibility   Activity Bar, Bottom Panel & Side Panel
> items visibility and order   Views visibility, location and order

Comment: Another interesting approach: transient profile (for a quick test): https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/154460 for VSCode 1.71 (Aug. 2022)