# How do I disable all extraneous extensions in the VS Code "Extension Development Host" without it overwriting my normal user-config?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, configuration-files

I'm trying to debug / develop on a VSCode extension. To do so, I need to disable all of my (many) other extensions in the debugging "Extension Development Host."

Doing so, however, *saves* to my user-preferences, which then causes … all of my other VScode instances … to stop having any extensions.

How can I disable my other, everyday extensions in the "Extension Development Host" without screwing up my normal user-config? Is there a way to convince the EDH to use a different settings-file or configuration-path or something, repeatedly and reliably?

Comment: Running the command `Developer: Reload with Extensions Disabled` in the Extension Development Host seem seems  to work for me.  Has no effect on the settings or the availablity of the extensions in other vscode windows.

Answer (score 4):

You can disable all extensions with the `--disable-extensions` flag. Just reconfigure your `.vscode/launch.json` (see args array):

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Run Extension",
            "type": "extensionHost",
            "request": "launch",
            "args": [
                "--extensionDevelopmentPath=${workspaceFolder}",
                "--disable-extensions"
            ],
            "outFiles": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/out/**/*.js"
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "${defaultBuildTask}"
        },
        ...
```

Answer (score 3):

See [Support extension debugging in a clean environment](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/159572#issuecomment-1231859949).  And [v1.72 Release Notes Extension debugging in a clean environment](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_72.md#extension-debugging-in-a-clean-environment)

You must have this setting enabled for the following technique to work in Stable v1.71+:

```
Workbench > Experimental > Settings Profile: Enabled
```

> With the "settings profile" feature and the new command line support
> for profiles it is now possible to specify profiles in the extension's
> debug configuration.
>
> There are basically two possible approaches:
>
> "debugging in a clean environment" by using an unnamed "empty" profile
> that gets automatically deleted when debugging has stopped.
>
> "debugging in a controlled environment" by using a named profile that
> has been created specifically for extension debugging and contains
> specific settings and extensions.
>
> This debug configuration shows how to "debug in a clean environment":

```
{
    "name": "Extension",
    "type": "extensionHost",
    "request": "launch",
    "args": [
        "--profile-temp",
        "--extensionDevelopmentPath=${workspaceFolder}",
        "${workspaceFolder}/sampleWorkspace"
    ],
    "outFiles": [
        "${workspaceFolder}/dist/**/*.js"
    ],
    "preLaunchTask": "npm: watch"
}
```

> Please note: the configuration from above passes a workspace folder
> ${workspaceFolder}/sampleWorkspace which is currently mandatory for
> the --profile-temp option. If the workspace folder argument is
> missing, the --profile-temp option is silently ignored. We will try to
> remove this requirement soon (see issue #159577).

- The above requirement has been remeoved in the Insiders Build

So, for example, I have the following `args` in a launch configuration:

```
    "args": [
      "--profile-temp",

      // some folder is necessary for now in Stable (but not Insiders), using the `${workspaceFolder}` variable
      "${workspaceFolder}/../OneDrive/Test Bed",

      "--extensionDevelopmentPath=${workspaceFolder}"
   ]
```

and it works well.  The ExtensionHost has no extensions installed, but my other vscode windows are unaffected.

Below from [v1.72 Release Notes Extension debugging in a clean environment](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_72.md#extension-debugging-in-a-clean-environment)

Please note: when debugging an extension in a remote location (via the "Remote Development" extensions "Containers", "SSL", or "WSL"), using the `--profile-temp` flag will result in this status message:

[image: temporary profile in a remote situation error message]

This is expected because the temporary profile does not include any extensions, which means that the "Remote Development" extensions are missing too. For remote scenarios it is recommended to create an empty named profile, add the "Remote Development" extensions to it, and then use the `--profile=....` command line option.

Comment: As a note, I recently upgraded to 1.72.2 and discovered this feature, but couldn't get it to work without `Workbench > Experimental > Settings Profile: Enabled` checked. Are you sure that's no longer required?

Comment: @ChrisWilson You are right, thanks.  I remember checking for it...  The setting isn't mentioned in the Release Notes link above which they normally do.