debug vscode extension from start every time without memory of previous run or cache
I am creating a VScode extension and every time I run the debugger it opens the vscode window with every tab and setting i tried in the previous run.
Is there a setting anywhere so that I can debug my extension freshly clear without any previous changes to setting or open editor from previous session?
This has been a problem because it once even added old default configuration in my package.json file to the settings.json and made me think its a bug on my side.
I tried googling it but i can not find any explanation where this setting could be
I am using vscode on linux ubuntu.

Is this what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73589372/836330

I have tried it but it does not have the effect I want. The files I have opened in previous debug sessions are still there and the settings I have changed for the extension I am debugging are also there.
