# How to read vscode keybindings within an extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am writing an extension that does things with keyboard shortcuts. I would like to read all current shortcuts and act accordingly. Currently I am reading them from this file:

`~/Library/Application Support/Code/storage.json`

Is there a way to pull that from `vscode` module instead?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/41397157/836330 for how to get and read `keybindings.json`.  If you are not in something like a `CompletionProvider` (where it is easy to get and read keybindings.json) I don't believe there is any way to get it through an api.

Answer (score 0):

You need to perform some steps, once you tested the current implementation.

1. Set a contribution [point](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/contribution-points).
2. Create a manifest as shown [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/extension-manifest)
3. Use a command on the [VS code API](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api) to perform your action
4. Publish it to the extensions market place. Alternatively package it
   into a VSIX. [More info](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/working-with-extensions/publishing-extension#packaging-extensions).